# Unable to build my app cause ConfigureServices returns error

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm new in ASP.NET and on making all of these things working right.

I want to get data from my MSSQL database, and pass it to my Angular web application, you know like simple Frontend <-> Backend communication so I made Data model looking like this::

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI_1.Models
{
    public class Users
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Imie { get; set; }
        public string Nazwisko { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Haslo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also I had a DataContext file looking like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebAPI_1.Models;

namespace WebAPI_1.Data
{
    public class DataContext: DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { } //wywołuje konst bazowy i przekazuje opcje

        public DbSet<Users> Users { get ; set; }
    }
}
```

Everything in that files working i guess fine, but i have only one **CS0161 Error** in the Startup.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WebAPI_1.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data.Sql;

namespace WebAPI_1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public object ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(s => s.UseSqlServer("ConnectionString"));

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddMvc(services => services.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

The error description from my IDE (VS 2019):

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0161  'Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection)': not all code paths return a value  WebAPI_1    C:\Users\Michal\source\repos\WebAPI_1\WebAPI_1\Startup.cs   29  Active
*

**What i already know:**

- I don't undrstand why i got this error
- It's because  *services.AddDbContext(s => s.UseSqlServer("ConnectionString"));* doesen't return anything

**In conclusion, i want to ask you for help and possible sollutions.**

Comment: `ConfigureServices` usually returns `void`. Why is yours declared as returning `object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ConfigureServices` method wants to return an `object`. I guess it should not return anything (`void`).

Comment: Thanks for reply, could you have any idea how to make 
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(s => s.UseSqlServer("ConnectionString"));
working in that casE?

Comment: As far as I can see, that should just work fine. Do you get an error message?

Comment: nope, now i saw the problem, you was right, thank you\